# How to select a row of a dataframe depending of 2 columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-analysis

I currently have the following problem.

I have a data frame of 150.000 rows and 4 columns, I need to filter by Profile ID (per day) and keep the last transaction that the user made (Profile ID), here is an example:

[image]

In the following image, the user ID "aToPCmXnXnOCgoGqEOVxY5pEnNM0h1" made two transactions, however, the last one he made (based on the Date column) is row 3656.

What is the best way to select that row?

Initially, I thought about performing a double loop with an If inside, but it is very inefficient and time-consuming to perform this task.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
library(dplyr)

df |> group_by(Profile.ID) |> summarise(Purchase = tail(Purchase , 1))
|> left_join(df)
```